# How do I stub a module method's callback with sinon?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, chai, sinon

I'm using the mv module to move files, an older module that still gets a lot of downloads and has been helpful in dealing with moving files between docker volumes and also outside of docker. I created a method to treat mv method as a promise.

When unit testing, I'm struggling to mock mv when used within a method.

```
import mv from 'mv';

export class CmdUtils {
  /**
   * Move a file to a new location. Using mv, this will attempt a mv command, however
   * this could fail with docker volumes and will fallback to the mv module streaming
   * data to the new location as needed.
   * @param filePath - Full path to file
   * @param destinationFilePath - Full path to file's new destination
   */
  public static moveFile = (filePath: string, destinationFilePath: string): Promise<void> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      mv(filePath, destinationFilePath, err => {
        if (!err) {
          resolve();
        } else {
          console.error('moveFile err', err);
          reject(err);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Here's a starting test with gaps:

```
import mv from 'mv';
import { CmdUtils } from './cmd-utils';

describe("CmdUtils: moveFile", () => {
  it("should successfully move a file using mv module", async () => {
    const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
    try {
      const moveFromPath = '/full/path/to/file.jpg';
      const moveToPath = '/full/path/to/destination/file.jpg';

      // Starting attempt at a replacement callback
      const mvCallback = (err: Error) => {
        if (!err) {
          Promise.resolve();
        } else {
          console.error('moveFile err', err.message);
          Promise.reject(err);
        }
      }

      // Stub mv
      sandbox.stub(mv)
      // What am I missing here?

      // Move file
      await CmdUtils.moveFile(moveFromPath, moveToPath);

      // expect no errors... (will revisit this)
    } finally {
      sandbox.restore();
    }
  });
});
```

How do I mock a successful file move? I'm seeing similar questions, yet not finding an answer just yet.

Comment: The way `moveFile` is set up doesn't allow for stubbing the cb to `mv`. You are not passing a callback as an argument, therefore cannot stub it to use it in `mv`. Seems you will need to rework `moveFile` to access a callback and pass that to `mv` to be executed.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @AndrewNolan. As coffee absorbs, I'm thinking the real question is how do I unit test a method that contains mv? I'm not so worried about what mv is doing, only that the moveFile() method behaves as it should. Let me know if this makes sense as I expand on unit testing ability.

Comment: My coffee is just now kicking in too :D . To achieve a stub, extract the callback that you apply to `mv` and pass it as a named param to `moveFile`. Then that named param is passed as the callback to `mv`. Then you can check it the callback behaves with `resolve` or `reject`. I will type up an "answer" in a moment.

Comment: Copy. I wonder though for purposes of functionality if I should pass in a named parameter to make unit tests work e.g. `moveFile('orig.jpg', 'new.jpg', someCallbackIDontCareAbout)`. My only concern in using moveFile() is the successful move of a file as a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class CmdUtil {
  static moveFileCb(resolve, reject, err) {
    if (!err) {
      resolve('RESOLVED');
    } else {
      reject(err);
    }
  }

  static moveFile() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      mv('test', 'test', CmdUtil.moveFileCb.bind(this, resolve, reject))
    })
  }
}
```

then the test could be something similar to what you have where you now stub `moveFileCb`. With that stub, you can check/assert what the callback was called with, how many times it was called, etc.

Side Note: I didn't write a test using `bind`. That might throw a wrench into the solution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll follow up/try it out on the next break.

Comment: In the end, I ended up using built-in promisify to reduce lines and omitted from tests as I had 90%+ coverage, covering the things I had more control over, including methods that used this one (they could handle errors).